# Migrating Hive Transaction table to another cloud platform

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, orc

I'm trying to migrate my **Hive Transaction table** to another cloud platform. As a POC work I copied a partition directory to another location and created a new hive transaction table with the same schema pointing to the copied location. Then I executed the following command to add the partition to meta store.

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> ADD PARTITION (date_time='2020-03-06',bin='95');
SHOW PARTITIONS <table name>
```

RESULT => date_time=2020-03-06/bin=95

But when I execute a select query I'm getting empty results. Any steps that I'm missing here?

Thank you very much in advance.